# How can I vent a portable A/C unit through bars on a window?

Tags: air-conditioning

I need a way to fit the vent from my portable a/c unit through the bars on my window.  The window bars are installed for security purposes and the average hose is way too wide.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Since shopping questions are off topic, I've edited your question to better fit the scope of the site.

Comment: Ask the warden if you can install an enclosure around the window that will attach to the hose and funnel air out.

Comment: I was expecting a response of this sort.  Funny!

Answer (score 1):

A picture might be helpful here, but generally speaking, any HVAC installer should be able to create an "adapter" out of sheet metal to fit between the bars and connect to your hose. It's not critical that it maintain the same shape, so you can convert from a round hose to a square vent as long as it supports the same or larger volume of airflow.

Just as an example, my stoves exhaust fan has a round duct, but I have a rectangular vent on the outside of my house.

Comment: Wood might be a simpler choice for *some* parts of the adapter. Complicated shapes out of sheet metal can be a real bear with typical basement-shop tools.